# Can I instantiate a Polyline without a GoogleMap?

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I have an `ArrayList<LatLng>` that I need to submit to an API as an encoded `Polyline`. What I've used before is something like:

```
PolylineOptions pathOptions = new PolylineOptions();    
Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(pathOptions);
polyline.setPoints(getRouteLatLngs());
```

except that in the case where I'm uploading, I don't have a `GoogleMap` to create the `Polyline` for me. Is it possible to create a `Polyline` without a `GoogleMap` or do I need to make another plan?

Comment: Are you sure your API asks for object of type polyline? Is this a restfull API?

Comment: It asks for an encoded polyline that is then decoded and stored on the server. I presume this is a useful format on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the `Polyline` object from GoogleMap. You need a tool to encode a list a points like [PolyUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html), available in [googlemaps utils library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils)

```
PolyUtil.encode(latLngPath)
PolyUtil.decode(encodedPath)
```